# Deploy internal to organization

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any documentation on how to deploy a **react-native-ios application** from say a website to be installed on a iOS device without uploading the package to the AppStore?

This app has no need to be in the AppStore, its intended for an organization to accept donations internally and store in the cloud. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building an in-house app you'll first need to get an [Enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) account; this kind of account allows you to distribute apps that can be downloaded by any iOS device without going through the Apple App Store. Unlike distributing to specific devices on your account (which is limited), or using TestFlight to distribute to testers, enterprise apps don't have limitations on the number of devices (note that it's only intended for in-house distributions and should not be abused as an alternative app distribution channel).

Regarding deployment: you build and package your app as you would do with any other iOS app. There's no difference if it's a RN app. Once you have an app signed with your enterprise certificate and provisions, you can distribute it from any remote site "over the air", you can find some documentation about it [here](https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7). You can also use a third party solution like AppCenter (HockeyApp), AppBlade etc. which takes care of creating downloadable links for your distribution, manage different app versions, users and so on.